# PHP escaping syntax again

Tags: php, escaping

Thanks again for the help with a similar question earlier. I have one more similar, but I think more complicated.

It looks like this in HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="formButtonDeleteButton" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('WADADeleteRecordID').value=<?php echo($row_WADAactivities2['ActivityID']); ?>;document.getElementById('WADADeleteRecordName').innerHTML='<?php echo($row_WADAactivities2['Activity']); ?>';document.getElementById('deleteBox').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('deleteMessage').style.display = 'table';" />
```

I get so far with it, but just get a bit lost, e.g.:

```
echo '<input type="button" class="formButtonDeleteButton" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('WADADeleteRecordID').value=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['ActivityID']) . ;document.getElementById('WADADeleteRecordName').innerHTML=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['Activity']);';document.getElementById('deleteBox').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('deleteMessage').style.display = 'table';" \"/>";
```

This is pretty much the last bit of something I've been looking at that needs tidying up.

Thanks again.

Comment: What do you exactly want? What similar question earlier? *tidying up* how? I doubt i'm the only one confused here

Comment: What do you mean by *"it looks like this in HTML"*? As in what you see in *View Page Source*? Where are those `<?php` tags coming from?

Comment: Break it up into multiple lines and functions.

Comment: You should be more concerned about writing monstruosities like PHP generating a multiline javascript function inside an HTML tag than escaping quotes within quotes, in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all the single-quote characters that are inside the single-quoted string:

```
echo '<input type="button" class="formButtonDeleteButton" value="" onclick="document.getElementById(\'WADADeleteRecordID\').value=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['ActivityID']) . ;document.getElementById(\'WADADeleteRecordName\').innerHTML=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['Activity']);';document.getElementById(\'deleteBox\').style.display = \'block\';document.getElementById(\'deleteMessage\').style.display = \'tabl\e';" \"/>";
```

I strongly recommend against writing such long strings of inline Javascript. Move it out into a Javascript function, and use `onclick="functionName(...)"`.

Answer (score 0):

See, you should always decide on whether or not its necessary to even echo something like this, or instead just use short tags like `<?=$someVar?>` directly in your view section of the code.  Why?  Because its much easier to deal with NOT escaping quotes :D  Anyway, the way you should choose your quotes single or double, is if you're planning on NOT having any variables inside the string, use single quotes..if you're planning on using variables in the string use double quotes to avoid having to concatenate.  Since you've used single quotes, you don't have to escape doubles, but you do have to escape other single quotes inside:

```
echo '<input type="button" class="formButtonDeleteButton" value=""     onclick="document.getElementById(\'WADADeleteRecordID\').value=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['ActivityID']) .' ;document.getElementById(\'WADADeleteRecordName\').innerHTML=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities2['Activity']).';document.getElementById(\'deleteBox\').style.display = \'block\';document.getElementById(\'deleteMessage\').style.display = \'table\';" />';
```